# Magento 1.5: rename 'Company' on billing and *with diff. name* on shipping

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I want to change the name of the field 'company' in frontend separatly for billing and shipping step.

In billing step, the costumer should see "Firma".
In shipping step, the costumer should see "Firma; c/o; fuer Packstation Postnummer"

So, it doesn't work for me with the translation.csv, because if I change the name of "company", it alwasy changes for billing and shipping step.

Does anyone know where I can change it?

Thanks a lot!!

Best regards, Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You could change the string in the template, so you ahve to unique strings to translate.

Answer (score 0):

Better to add two rows in translave.csv, saying "Billing Company" and "Shipping Company" with their respecting names "Firma" and "Firma; c/o; fuer Packstation Postnummer".

And then edit the billing.phtml and shipping.phtml (in your theme's template/checkout/onepage/ directory), changing Company with their respective name.. like in billing.phtml change the `$this->__('Company')` to `$this->__('Billing Company')` and in shipping.phtml, change the  `$this->__('Company')` to  `$this->__('Shipping Company')`

Comment: Thanks! I will try. Do I have to change 'Company' in both cases?`<div class="field"> <label for="billing:company"><?php echo $this->__('**Company**') ?></label></code> <div class="input-box"> <input type="text" id="billing:company" name="billing[company]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('**Company**') ?>" class="input-text" /> </div> </div> `

Comment: Yes. the text inside `$this->__('*')` will get translated.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. It was a little bit tricky, because an extension overlayed the billing.phtml and shipping.phtml (in your theme's template/checkout/onepage/ directory). But after found it out, it was exactly the way it works perfect. Thank you very much for your fast help!